# Javascript Slug Generation Function Giving Improper Output

Tags: javascript, jquery, slug

I am using below function in jquery to generate URL slug

```
var text = $("#post_title").val();

var converted = text.toLowerCase().replace(/ /g,'-').replace(/[^\w-]+/g,'');
$("#post_slug").val(converted);
```

I want to create a proper slug that does not have any numeric values and no additional `-` (Hyphens)

What's happening with the above code is as follows

I am using the following title to generate a slug

title: `top 5 ways to get in list`

slug: `top-5-ways-to-get-in-list`

I want to avoid numeric values in slug so it should be like below

slug: `top-ways-to-get-in-list`

also if there is any space slug especially at the end then the slug becomes, I want to avoid any `-` unwanted hyphens

slug: `top-ways-to-get-in-list-`

I am not able to figure out that what's wrong in the code.

Answer (score 2):

```js
function generateSlug(text) {
  return text.trim().toLowerCase()
    .replace(/[0-9]+/g, '')
    .replace(/ +/g, '-');
}

console.log(generateSlug('Top 5 ways to get in list'));
console.log(generateSlug('Top 5 ways to get in list5'));
console.log(generateSlug('Top 5 ways to get in list5 '));
console.log(generateSlug(' Top 5 ways to get in list '));
console.log(generateSlug('  Top  5  ways  to  get  in  list  '));
```

Comment: if I use a string like this `Top 5 ways to get in list5-` then I get slug like `top-ways-to-get-in-list5-`

Answer (score 0):

No matter its a function or not, you can you this on any JS code

```
var Text = 'Faa fee foo fog   my code has bug' 
      Text = Text.toLowerCase();
      Text = Text.trim();
      Text = Text.replace('/\s/g','-');
      Text = Text.replace(/ +/g,'-');
```

just use the Text where ever you need